# Android: Need app's Audio Volume Seekbar to change totally independed of the device volume

Tags: android, volume, seekbar, android-audiomanager

I need my in-app volume seekbar to change the volume of the audio in my app only.  I need it to be totally separate from the main volume of the device.  Everything I find changes the device volume when I change the slider in my app.

I want users to have the option of playing audio in my app at a low volume, but maybe still have their device turned up so phone calls and alarms and such could still be at their normal high volume.

How can I make a seekbar in my app only control audio in my app and not bother other device volumes?  Here is the code I am using:

Called in onCreate method:

```
VolumeControls();
```

Outside of that:

```
private void VolumeControls() {

        final TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sbVolume);

        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        seekBar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        seekBar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

        txtView.setText(String.valueOf(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)));

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0){
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0){
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2)
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
                txtView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }
        });
}
```